# Cannot assign screen to task

Tags: processmaker

I don't know whether this is the expected behavior, but when I create a screen and try to assign it to a task in my process, it doesn't seem to stick.

Specifically, I'm talking about "Screen for input" box in the "Edit Process" page. When I click the dropdown button, it shows my screen's name (strangely with red background). When I select the screen its name is displayed in the box. But when I select another task and then go back to the first, the box is still empty (with the dropdown list opened). I tried saving after selecting the screen, but when I backed out and choose to edit the same process again, the box would still be empty.

Any idea what I messed up?

Comment: which release of processmaker4 are u using? and is there any errors in log file?

Comment: I find that behavior strange, I have not replicated that problem.
What version did you install? you could try with the latest version 4.1.18
https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/releases I hope that solves your problem